# Linking of Lists columns in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Scenario:

There is a List named **TestList**. This list contains 4 columns AppName, AppID, Domain and Owner.
Here Owner is Person field type and rest are single line of text.

Now, there are 4 different Lists. TestList1,TestList2,TestList3 and TestList4.
These lists are provided with List Level Permissions with usergroup1, usergroup2, usergroup3 and usergroup4 respectively.

In each of the above lists there are 8 columns. And the first columns in each lists are looked up from **TestList** and the next four are entered manually.

Now, depending on the Owner column in **TestList** the AppName in all these different lists should only auto populate their AppNames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select AppName as a dependent column when creating a lookup column.